# Reshape2 dcast() function returning wrong values

Tags: r, pivot, reshape, reshape2

I have tick data for the equities in the Dow Jones Industrial Average over the course of the day. Here is a sample of the data:

```
> head(df)
                        TS  Sym      Ask
1: 2015-03-24 14:00:00.000 YMM5 17956.00
2: 2015-03-24 14:00:00.002 AAPL   126.91
3: 2015-03-24 14:00:00.005  UNH   118.35
4: 2015-03-24 14:00:00.009  XOM    84.64
5: 2015-03-24 14:00:00.014  AXP    81.35
6: 2015-03-24 14:00:00.016   PG    84.19
```

I am trying to use the dcast() function of reshape2 to transform the data into wide format, so it will look like:

```
                        TS   AAPL   AXP    PG    UNH   XOM
1: 2015-03-24 14:00:00.000 126.91 81.35 84.19 118.35 84.64
```

When I try the following set of commands though, here is what I get:

```
tick <- data.table(read.csv("2015-3-24.csv"))
df<- data.table(TS = tick$DateTime, Sym = tick$Symbol, Ask = tick$Ask, Bid = tick$Bid)
tmp <- dcast(data = df, formula = TS ~ Sym)

head(tmp)


                       TS AAPL AXP BA CAT CSCO CVX DD DIS GE GS HD IBM INTC JNJ JPM KO MCD MMM MRK MSFT NKE PFE PG TRV UNH UTX V VZ WMT XOM YMM5
1 2015-03-24 14:00:00.000    0   0  0   0    0   0  0   0  0  0  0   0    0   0   0  0   0   0   0    0   0   0  0   0   0   0 0  0   0   0    1
2 2015-03-24 14:00:00.002    1   0  0   0    0   0  0   0  0  0  0   0    0   0   0  0   0   0   0    0   0   0  0   0   0   0 0  0   0   0    0
3 2015-03-24 14:00:00.005    0   0  0   0    0   0  0   0  0  0  0   0    0   0   0  0   0   0   0    0   0   0  0   0   1   0 0  0   0   0    0
```

I know I am getting the formula wrong or something, but no matter what I have though to try I am getting the same result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there other messages returned by `dcast`?

Comment: Yes, `"Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length''` Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues with your post, I'd like to get clarified: (too long for comment, so this is a guess at best as of now.)

- No reproducible example.
- You use `data.table`, but the version is not shown. `data.table` provides efficient implementations of `melt` and `dcast`. In versions <= 1.9.4, you might want to use `dcast.data.table`. From versions `1.9.5+`, you can directly use `dcast()` without loading `reshape2`. So I'm not sure if you're using `dcast` from `reshape2` or from the devel version of `data.table`.
- Your formula (if not a typo) is wrong for the result you've shown.

You've not shown the entire result from `dcast`, I believe. If it complains something about

> Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'

then your id and measure vars in formula do not uniquely identify cells. With the minimal info provided, I can only guess that this is indeed your issue.

Comment: I edited the post to fix the typo I made earlier, so that the result is representative of the actual input of TS ~ Sym. I am getting the Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length' message. I tried dcast() without reloading reshape2 and got the same result. Thank you.